# [HELP]Java StackOverflow Error with BST Recursive Insert

Tags: java, recursion, insert, binary-search-tree

I im trying to write a BST with a recursive Insert method, but it seemd like I am stuck on a line where the program does not jump out.

It works if the element keys are sorted while calling insert from Main, it does not work if they are not sorted and I cant figure out why.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    BST bst = new BST();

    bst.insert(2,"Val_0");
    bst.insert(1,"Val_1");
}

public class BSTNode {

public int key;
public String val;
public BSTNode left, right, parent;

public BSTNode(int key, String val) {
    this.key = key;
    this.val = val;
    this.left = new BSTNode();
    this.right = new BSTNode();
    this.parent = new BSTNode();
}

public BSTNode() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

}

public class BST {

private BSTNode root;
public BST() {
    this.root = null;   
} 

    public void insert(int key, String val) {

    root = insertRec(new BSTNode(key,val));
    }

    private BSTNode insertRec(BSTNode node) {

    if (root == null) {
        root = node;
        return root;
    }

    if (node.key < root.key) {
        root.left = insertRec(root.left);
        root.left.parent = root;



    }if( node.key > root.key) {
        root.right = insertRec(root.right);
        root.left.parent = root;
    }


    return node;
     }
}
```

The error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError, debugger shows a loop at node.key < root.key

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: My constructor was creating elements for left right and parent everytime together with insert method.

```
public class BSTNode {

public int key;
public String val;
public BSTNode left, right, parent;

public BSTNode(int key, String val) {
    this.key = key;
    this.val = val;
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
    this.parent = null;
}
```

------//----------
Also changed the methods a bit:

```
public void insert(int key, String val) {
    root = insertRec(root, new BSTNode(key,val));

}

private BSTNode insertRec(BSTNode currentParent,BSTNode node) {
    if (currentParent == null) {
        return node;
    }

    if (node.key < currentParent.key) {
        currentParent.left = insertRec(currentParent.left,node);
        currentParent.left.parent = currentParent;

    }if(node.key > currentParent.key) {
        currentParent.right = insertRec(currentParent.right,node);
        currentParent.right.parent = currentParent;
    }


    return currentParent;
}
```